# php mysql matching and return value

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables are :

```
studens_exam_answers_tbl
----------------------------------------------------
exam_id | question_id | student_id  | student_answer 
----------------------------------------------------
    10       1           6              1 
    10       2           6              4
    10       3           6              3
    10       4           6              0
    10       5           6              5
    10       1           5              1
    10       2           5              2
    10       3           5              2
    10       4           5              5
    10       5           5              5

question_poll__tbl
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
question_id | question  | option_1 |  option_2 | ....| option_5 |correct_answer
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1          ....         ....       ....      ...    ....        5
    2          ....         ....       ....      ...    ....        2
    3          ....         ....       ....      ...    ....        3
    4          ....         ....       ....      ...    ....        4
    5          ....         ....       ....      ...    ....        1
```

I want to match student answers with correct answers with sql. If students answer is correct 'it is true' else 'false'. if student_answer is 0 'empty'.

How can i do it?

Comment: You want to do it sql means? You want to add another column in studens_exam_answers_tbl to store true false or empty.

Comment: Have you tried any query?

Comment: join and compare, it's not that hard...

Comment: I'm too lazy to try to create such a query, but it's possible: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

Comment: First normalize your data. A table is NOT a spreadsheet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 Select student id, (Case when student_answer=0
    then ""
    else
    when student_answer=correct_answer then "true"
    else "false"
    end ) as Result
    from studens_exam_answers_tbl inner join question_poll__tbl on studens_exam_answers_tbl.question_id.question_id =question_poll__tbl.question_id
```

Comment: you are using the same table columns check before posting it should be  studens_exam_answers_tbl.question_id =question_poll__tbl.question_id

Comment: There is a typ0 in `corrct_answer`. Should be `correct_answer`.